# Multi-user flexible-declarative-schema database management webapp

Tags: web-apps, database, multi-user

I'm looking for a webapp that can be flexibly and easily customized with a given data schema and then allow multiple users to manage the data

Important:

- Quick to implement, *declarative* schema/model
- Users get a flexible and intuitive UI for managing both entities and their attributes, and *relationships between entities* (almost like a graph db)

Nice to haves:

- Uses any SQL backend
- Schema can automatically capture historical state of entities, attributes or relationships
- Some type of SSO authentication

Comment: Does it have to use a SQL backend?  Or would noSQL be acceptable if there are some data constraint abilities on the schema?

Comment: noSQL would be ok

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you'd want to have a look at [Simitless](https://simitless.com/en). If I understand your question correctly, it should fit what you are looking for:

- uses a declarative data model,
- supports OAuth/SSO with Facebook, Google, LinkedIn, Microsoft, Slack, Twitter,
- enables you to create your own database management web app - it gives you modules/fields (like spreadsheet columns) that you can select from and tailor the app to track/collect only the data you need,
- I think it has quite an intuitive and flexible UI as well,
- uses noSQL backend (you said it would be ok as well),
- you can have as many parallel connections as you want (checks your multi-user requirement),
- has quite a few templates to choose from when building your own data web app.

Here is a screenshot of how one of the templates with dummy data looks like:
[image]

May be a worth a look.

**Full disclosure: I am part of the startup that designed that platform.** We just launched recently, still in beta. If you want to try it out and need some help, I can definitely give you a hand.